# Vim edit file listed in current buffer

Tags: vim

If I have opened in vim a file with the following contents

```
foo.html
bar/baz.html
```

I currently have to type

```
:e bar/baz.html
```

to open that file for editing.

I'd prefer to have a command that automatically uses the current line.

Even better would be taking the visual selection instead of the whole line or even pattern matching since of course in the real file it looks like this

```
<a [...] href="bar/baz.html" [...]>
```

It should be possible to define a custom command for that in the .vimrc but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the target filename under the cursor and press `gf`. You can also do it with visual selection, such that, in the line below,

```
I want to open xfilex without the exes!
```

if you want to open `file` (not `xfilex`), then visually select `file` and press `gf`.

Find more information with `:help gf`:

```
[count]gf       Edit the file whose name is under or after the cursor.
                Trailing punctuation characters ".,:;!" are ignored. 
                Escaped spaces "\ " are reduced to a single space.
```